# calculate an average for each new sample that arrives, with equal weight

Tags: c, math, average

How do I calculate in C an average for each new sample that arrives from time to time, with equal weight ?
is this called 'moving average' ?
i Mean calculating the average from the start until requested by the user

Comment: A "moving average" is one where you calculate the average of the last X values. If you receive value X + 1 then you discard the first value so only the last X values are used.

Comment: This can be implemented efficiently with a ring buffer and additionally a variable holding the entire sum: subtract oldest value from sum, overwrite it in ring-buffer and add new value to the sum. Average is naturally the quotient of total sum and number of elements in the ring-buffer...

Comment: If you want to continuously update an overall average, you don't even need the ring buffer.  Do the mathematical equivalent of taking the old average, multiplying by the old N, adding in your new sample, incrementing N, and dividing by the new N.

Comment: @Steve Summit what do you mean by old N?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what type of average you want to implement: The average of all samples from the start until now or the average of the last X samples?

Comment: @gaas I'm assuming you'll have variables for: your average so far, and the number of values you've read so far.  I was using N to represent the number of values you've read so far.

Comment: An average is the sum of all values, divided by the value count, right? So when a new value comes in then update the sum by adding the new value, increase the count, and do the division again.

Comment: but that's the question, how to calculate over time the average ? for each second I am given 2 samples, what to do with them?

Comment: @gaas What don't you understand in Some programmer dude's comment? initialize `sum` and `count` to 0 at the beginning. When you get a new sample: `sum += current_sample; count++; average = sum / count;`. Depending on the value range for the samples and the number of samples you have to choose suitable data types. Integer types may overflow when you add the new sample or increment the value; with floating point types you may reach a point when adding a new sample or incrementing the value no longer changes the value. In these cases the calculation will get more complicated.

Comment: @SteveSummit There are two problems with your approach, though: The old average might suffer from being rounded, thus multiplying by `N` might not yield the exact value (well, can be handled by storing the sum instead); then if continuously accumulating new averages then the product at some point will overflow (or the sum, if using that variant). All this is avoided by the moving average, where the ring-buffer allows to correctly remove the oldest value again...

Comment: @Aconcagua Be that as it may, a moving average is simply *wrong* if that's not what the requirement is! (Also correctly implementing a ring buffer is considerably beyond the skills being exercised at this point in the OP's instruction, I suspect.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Maybe – still I wouldn't want to leave her/him without that information for not running into surprises when overflow finally occurs ;) Admitted, requirements are not clearly specified, the moving average is just mentioned.

Comment: @Aconcagua Assuming sum kept as `double`, any approach will be fine (no overflow, no appreciable roundoff error) for "reasonable" inputs.  But if the inputs are sufficiently extreme, it's not a given that use of a ring buffer will "correctly remove the oldest value again"!

Comment: `double`? Honestly? This would make rounding issues even worse, precision is less than the one of an equally sized integral. Sure, overflow is avoided, but reaching an 'infinity' value (much later, admitted again) isn't of value any more either. Still you just brought big-integer libraries to my mind – I'd go with such one to avoid any such problems for a very long time – if running for such a long time is an issue at all ;)

Comment: *'[...] sufficiently extreme [...]'* – well, of course the type of the sum must be large enough to hold the sum of all extrema, if values are of type `[u]int[N]_t` you'd need a `[u]int[M*N]_t`, of course, `M` >= 2 – if need be for not existing emulated via `M` separate `[u]int[N]_t` values.

Comment: @SteveSummit Let's leave it at this: Either QA needs the entire sum, with or without big-integers, or a moving average. If the latter there's my answer (was for pure distraction from a heavier problem anyway), if not, someone else might or might not provide another one...

Answer (score 0):

Calculating a *moving average* can be done using a ring buffer:

```
int32_t data[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 }; // important: zero initialisation
                                   // of the entire array!
int64_t sum = 0;
size_t pos = 0;
bool filled = false; // include <stdbool.h> for

// on new sample received:
sum -= data[pos];  // remove the oldest value;
                   // 0 while filling, thus initialisation!
data[pos] = value; // store new value
sum += value;      // update sum with new value

// advance position in the ring buffer; note that advancing
// means restarting at the beginning if you reached the end:
if(++pos == sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data))
{
    pos = 0;
    filled = true;
}
size_t count = filled ? sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data) : pos;
int32_t average = (sum < 0 ? sum - count / 2 : sum + count / 2 )) / count;
// adding/subtracting half of the count rounds the value commercially
```

This is entirely untested code, though – if you find a bug, please fix yourself...